# Can't execute ssh from php

Tags: php, apache, ssh, sudo

I can't seem to execute the ssh command from any of the PHP functions like `exec`, `system`, `passthru` etc..

I've even tried `/bin/ssh` however no output is displayed

Any ideas? I can confirm that by doing "`su - www-data`" and then trying ssh works, meaning that the apache user has access to ssh..

Thanks

Update: Sorry everything, it appears that ssh is being run ok, it's the remote commands that arn't running. Example:

```
$remote_command = "/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/www-data/id_rsa testuser@10.0.1.10 'echo hi > /home/testuser/test'";
passthru($remote_command);
```

I am seeing traffic on the remote server, however the new file "test" isn't being created..

Comment: Could you show us some code you're using? In essence. calling ssh via the commandline should work, what exactly is going wrong depends on what you're tryning to do & how you do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the php exec functions only capture the standard output `stdout`, not the error output `stderr`. You should redirect `stderr` to `stdout` when executing your command, i.e. `passthru("ssh ... 2>&1");`.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in accepting the answer. It said I had to wait 5 minutes